# Running Tagged Tests in SBT Project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a SBT project where I have written a few unit tests and a few integration tests and I have tagged these integration tests such that I can leverage SBT to run these integration tests only in a specific environment. I have the following defined in my build.sbt:

```
addCommandAlias("integration-tests", "Integration/testOnly -- -n integrationTest")
lazy val IntegrationTest = config("integration").extend(Test)
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, DockerPlugin)
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    IntegrationTest / parallelExecution := false,
    Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-l", "integrationTest"),
  )
  .settings(
    inConfig(IntegrationTest)(Defaults.testTasks)
  )
  .settings(
    scalastyleFailOnError := false
  )
```

But when I tried to run the following command:

```
mymac@mac:~/Projects/sandbox-sbt-project$ sbt integration-tests
[info] IntegrationTests:
[info] Test:
[info] Test1
[info] Test2
[info] Test3
[info] Test4
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 874 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
```

It can be seen that none of my integration tests are executed. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Where do you have your tests and how do you tag them?

Comment: Tests are in src/tests as usual and I tag the integration tests

Comment: are you able to run your tagged tests only without a custom configuration scope?